# WPF contextmenu mouseover

Tags: wpf, binding, click, contextmenu, mouseevent

I am wondering if there is a way to bind the current `ContextMenu` item to a property in WPF without first clicking on it.

For example:

```
<MenuItem MaxHeight="20"
          HorizontalAlignment="left"
          Header="Radio Group"
          Name="cmRadio"
          ItemsSource="{Binding RadioGroups, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

I'm hoping to be able to figure out what item the mouse is over before clicking.

Sorry for the lack of description ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of "mouseover" events you could use, some totally in XAML.

[Similar Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734061/event-for-mouseover-action-in-wpf)

See farther down for the XAML answer.